# Windows Date and Time shows different options for Time zone

Tags: windows, time-zone

On one computer I see the following Time Zone:
(UTC+00:00) Casablanca

On a second computer I see the following Time Zone:
(UTC+01:00) Casablanca

One computer is running Windows 10, the other is running Windows Server 2016. Both are located next to my desk. All other date and time settings are the same.

Can anyone suggest why I am seeing this difference?

Comment: Likely a Microsoft DST error

Comment: http://northafricapost.com/26021-morocco-keeps-clocks-steady-on-gmt1.html (Found on the Wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morocco.)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Casablanca to set GMT or UTC.

Since 2018 Morocco is on [permanent daylight savings time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_in_Morocco) so is always 1 hour ahead of UTC/GMT, unlike the UK which changes, winter to summer.

Presumably, one of your computers hasn't been updated with that information.